# MySQL Transactional delete and Java

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, foreign-keys, constraints

I've got tables like this:

```
Table A:  
`id | name`

Table B:  
`id | A_id | ....`  

A_id is a foreign key to Table A, the Engine is InnoDB
```

This is the code that fails:

```
    String[] cleanupQueries = new String[] { "DELETE FROM B WHERE A_id = (SELECT id FROM A WHERE name = 'test')",
                                            "DELETE FROM A WHERE name = 'test'" };

    Connection connection;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionString());
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error establishing a database connection!");
    }

    try {
        for(String cleanupQuery : cleanupQueries) {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(cleanupQuery);
            statement.executeUpdate(); //FAILS WHEN EXECUTING THE SECOND QUERY
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while executing the queries in the transactional context!");
    }

    try {
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        rollback(connection);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while comitting!");
    }
```

The Exception i get is:
`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('DATABASE/TABLE', CONSTRAINT 'FK_B_A' FOREIGN KEY ('FK_A') REFERENCES 'A' ('ID') ON DEL)`

The database doesn't let me delete A while there are still B's left, but the first query deleted all B's. I want to delete all B's and the A they reference only completely.

I don't want to change the Tables to have cascading deletes. What shall i do to get the code working?

Answer (score 0):

Cause for error is

The Foreign Key has referenced to the table A id so if you would like to delete the F_Key , first you should delete the Child references values of that foreign keys then only its  possible to delete the parent.

Correct me if 'm wrong..

Comment: You're right, but i don't want to do it outside of the transactional context.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the cascade is true while deleting the foreign key constraint.The child table entry is automatically deleted when you delete the original parent entry.

Comment: I don't have influence to the database structure. I need to do it programatically, ensuring that the transaction is done only compeltely.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"DELETE FROM B WHERE A_id = (SELECT id FROM A WHERE name IN 'test')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the child rows are deleted in the same transaction, the deleted rows are still visible and thus the parent rows could not be deleted.
This may be because of the transaction isolation setting on the connection.  I would try different levels and see which one allows it.